# Share data tables between Spock test methods

Tags: testing, spock

When test methods within a Spock spec use the same data, is there a shortcut way to not have to repeat the same `where` block in each method?

Effectively, what this would be equivalent to having a spec-level `where` instead of one per "feature".

For example, see the way the where block is repeated in each test method ("feature") below:

```
ReindeerSpec extends Specification {

    List<Reindeer> reindeers() {
        [makeReindeerOneWay('donner'), makeReindeerSomeOtherWay('blitzen')]
    }

    def 'some test'(Reindeer reindeer) {

        expect:
        // some thing about this reindeer

        where:
        reindeer << reindeers()

    }

    def 'some other test'(Reindeer reindeer) {

        expect:
        // some other thing about this reindeer

        where:
        reindeer << reindeers()

    }

}
```

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: @Opal Many thanks for posting.  I spent some time looking further into this and came upon Spock extensions, which might be what I need.

Answer (score 2):

No there's no such way. `where` block must be present at the end of the method wen data-driven testing is used.

Answer (score 1):

@Opal is correct - there is no out-of-the-box way to do this.  However, after additional digging,  I discovered that Spock has a rich extension API.  The downside is that official documentation is nonexistent, and examples are sparse and tend to be several years old.

In very rough terms, and with the caveat that I haven't actually tried the following, an approach might entail:

Implement an ExtensionAnnotation and associated AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension.  When AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension.visitSpec() is called, modify the SpecInfo, adding a DataProviderInfo to each FeatureInfo.  The annotation would be applied once, possibly at the Spec level, or maybe on the data providing method (in my example, `reindeers()`.

If someone with experience implementing extensions cares to comment on this approach or provide an better alternative, I'd be very grateful.